# Проблема с созданием исключений

Tags: java, исключения

Код - простецкий симулятор банкомата.
Задание - тренировка во встраивании обработки исключений в код.

```
Atm.java
package ex2.atm;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Atm {

    Atm() {
    }


    boolean isCardInserted(Card card) {
        if (card != null) {
            System.out.println("card inside");
            return true;
        } else
            System.out.println("card already inside");
        return false;
    }

    String showBalance(Card card) {
        if (isCardInserted(card)) {
            System.out.println(card.getBalance());
            return null;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Вставьте карту");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void withdraw(Card card, BigDecimal request) {
        BigDecimal zero = new BigDecimal(0);
        if (((card.getBalance().subtract(request)).compareTo(zero)) < 0) {
            if (card.isCredit()) {
                card.creditIncreased(request);
                System.out.println("Вы должны банку: " + card.getDebt().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(-1)));
            } else System.out.println("Ваша карта не является кредитной");
        } else {
            card.setBalance(card.getBalance().subtract(request));
        }


    }


}

Card.java
package ex2.atm;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

abstract class Card {
    private long serialNumber;
    private BigDecimal balance;
    private boolean credit;
    private BigDecimal debt;

    protected Card() {
    }

    public Card(long serialNumber, BigDecimal balance, boolean credit, BigDecimal debt) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.credit = credit;
        this.debt = debt;
    }

    void creditIncreased(BigDecimal request) {
        this.balance = (BigDecimal.valueOf(0));
        BigDecimal tempBal = bigDecSub(this.balance, request);
        BigDecimal anotherTempBal = bigDecAdd(this.debt, tempBal);
        this.debt = (anotherTempBal);
    }

    BigDecimal bigDecSub(BigDecimal plus, BigDecimal minus) {
        return plus.subtract(minus);
    }

    BigDecimal bigDecAdd(BigDecimal plus, BigDecimal minus) {
        return plus.add(minus);
    }

    BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public boolean isCredit() {
        return credit;
    }

    public BigDecimal getDebt() {
        return debt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Card{" +
                "serialNumber=" + serialNumber +
                ", balance=" + balance +
                ", credit=" + credit +
                ", debt=" + debt +
                '}';
    }


}

Main.java
package ex2.atm;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Visa visa = new Visa(1921682550, BigDecimal.valueOf(5000), false, BigDecimal.valueOf(0));
        Atm teller = new Atm();
        System.out.println(teller.showBalance(visa));
        teller.withdraw(visa, BigDecimal.valueOf(700));

    }

}

Visa.java
package ex2.atm;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Visa extends Card {

    public Visa(long serialNumber, BigDecimal balance, boolean credit, BigDecimal debt) {
        super(serialNumber, balance, credit, debt);
    }

}
```

Вопрос:
Подскажите, а есть ли здесь вообще места, где можно хоть какие-то исключения обработать.
Если есть - не пишите готовый код. Лучше скажите что-то типа:

"в методе isCardInserted/Atm используй tryWithResourses для sout с исключением IOException".

Или может что-то добавить можно/нужно, чтобы создать "исключительные" ситуации.
Просто сколько читал всякие обучалки, там везде обработка исключений строится на BufferedReader, а у меня всяких потоков нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не вижу какие системные ошибки можно обрабатывать в Вашем примере. Вы действительно не обращаетесь ни к каким внешним ресурсам, которые могут выбрасывать ошибки, не зависящие от Вас (потоки, файлы, базы данных, и т.п.).

Но исключения используются не только для работы с внешними ресурсами, но и для внутренней логики приложения, т.ч. можно попробовать выбрасывать исключения самому и затем их обрабатывать.

Например, в методе `Atm.withdraw` Вы проверяете условие, что с некредитной карты нельзя снять сумму больше баланса. В этом случае Вы напрямую выводите сообщение пользователю.

```
else System.out.println("Ваша карта не является кредитной");
```

Вместо этого можно выбрасывать в этом случае исключение, и обрабатывать его в try-catch.

Это будет выглядит логичнее если `withdraw` будет методом класса `Card`. Так в классе `Card` будет проверка условий и выбрасывание исключений, а в классе `Atm` вызов методов, обработка исключений и вывод сообщений для пользователя.

Вообще, если все методы, изменяющие баланс будут в `Card`, то можно будет добиться того, что карточка никогда не окажется в неправильном состоянии. Сейчас класс `Atm` может сделать так для любой карты:

```
card.setBalance(BigDecimal.valueOf(-1000));
```

Если метода `setBalance` не будет, или же он будет `private`, то так уже не получится.

Преимуществом использования исключений в том что они прерывают работу любого метода в котором они не обрабатываются, что позволяет выполнять сложные операции и обрабатывать исключения централизованно:

```
try {
    card.withdraw(BigDecimal.valueOf(400));
    ...
    card.withdraw(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000));
    card.transfer(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
} catch(Exception e) {  
    //выполняются разные методы, но ошибки можно обработать в одном месте
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Исходя из логики приложения (симулятор банкомата), я бы предположил, что исключение надо выбрасывать в случае каких-то ошибок карты (например не читается карта) - в общем случае обычно это проверяется вызовом проверки готовности устройства перед началом работы:

```
   public boolean isCardReady(Card card) throws HardwareException {
      if(card == null)
         return false;
      return true; //на симуляторе всегда true
   }

   public boolean isAtmReady(Atm atm)  throws HardwareException {
      if (atm == null)
         return false;
      return true;
   }
```